# Natural Scrolling on Trackpad and Reversed Scrolling on Mouse

Tags: macos, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I'm using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.7.5. I recently got a wireless mouse to use for photoshop, gaming, etc.

I like my trackpad set to natural scrolling but I'm used to the scroll wheel on a mouse being set to reversed natural scrolling. Is there a way that I can set my trackpad to use natural scrolling, and set my mouse to use reversed scrolling at the same time?

Comment: Related questions at Ask Different: [20579](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20579/is-there-any-way-in-lion-to-have-natural-scrolling-for-trackpad-and-reverse), [22220](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/macbook-pro-with-lion-scrolling-via-trackpad-vs-mouse), [31102](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31102/how-can-i-enable-natural-scrolling-for-my-trackpad-but-disable-it-for-my-mouse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This free app called scroll reverser](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37872/scroll-reverser) has a setting that allows the mouse and the trackpad to be independently and simultaneously set to natural or reversed scrolling.

[[source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1194820)]